# Set permalinks/seo links for wordpress in heroku HHVM nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku, nginx, hhvm

I have blog inside "blog" folder and I try to set seo friendly (permalinks, "post name") for my wordpress blog on heroku.

just settings up my htccess result with 404.. errors

```
Options -Indexes
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I been told I need to set nginx config and work my way with try_files - so i generated `nginx_app.config`:

```
location /blog/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

and set it up inside procfile:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-hhvm-nginx -C nginx_app.conf
```

But I end up with 403 error.

Is there anything I miss on how to set up wordpress permalinks in heroku HHVM nginx ?

```
remote:        - hhvm (3.5.1)
remote:        - apache (2.4.20)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
```

- I tried many different configuration and search info online for 4 hours and end up with same/similar results.

Thanks!